# Python typing: mypy complains about bound TypeVar having incompatible type with subclass of that type

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

The following code results in the error `28: error: List item 0 has incompatible type "ExampleRule[<nothing>]"; expected "RuleSub"  [list-item]`. How can I change the type annotations to be correct?

```
from typing import *

EdgeSub = TypeVar('EdgeSub', bound='EdgeBase')
RuleSub = TypeVar('RuleSub', bound='RuleBase')


class EdgeBase:
    pass


class RuleBase(Generic[EdgeSub]):
    def proposeEdges(self) -> list[EdgeSub]:
        return []

    def allowEdge(self, edge: EdgeSub) -> bool:
        return True


class ExampleRule(RuleBase[EdgeSub]):
    def proposeEdges(self) -> list[EdgeSub]:
        return []

    def allowEdge(self, edge: EdgeSub) -> bool:
        return True


def get_rule_list() -> list[RuleSub]:
    weapon_rule_list: list[RuleSub] = [ExampleRule()]  # This is line 28 with the error
    return weapon_rule_list
```

Note that in the non-simplified implementation, `ExampleRule.proposeEdges` returns a list of instances of many different subclasses of `EdgeBase`, hence needing the `EdgeSub` type var. Similarly, `get_rule_list` needs to return many different types of rules.

Comment: `get_rule_list` doesn't need to be generic; you can use `list[RuleBase]`.

Comment: *Why* exactly doing that fixes the problem, I'm not entirely sure. Probably something related to variance.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't gotten my head wrapped around the nuances yet (nor some of the basics, for that matter).  Thanks!